# Which file system is the fastest?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8, formatting, ext3

I'm looking to format my hard drive. I've heard about a file system called "ext3", it's supposedly a linux partition and I think is a lot faster than NTFS.

But my question, is, is there anything faster than ext3? And how could I format my drive to that particular file system.

I'm using Windows 8.

[My Drive](http://www.seagate.com/external-hard-drives/portable-hard-drives/standard/goflex/)

Comment: Fastest in which operation? Fastest to do what? Fastest at the costs of a loss in stability?

Comment: EXT4 is an improvement.  But Windows does not support being installed on formats outside of Fat32, NTFS, exFat.  More important is your drive speed, if "speed" in the raw is the goal.

Comment: This is a subjective question. In practice, every filesystem has a "worst case" and a "best case" due to the limitations of practical computer science and known algorithms. That is, for every filesystem you show me, I can show you a benchmark where it performs worse than other filesystems, and another benchmark where it performs better. Some filesystems do well on a lot of benchmarks but fall flat on a few; poorly implemented filesystems do poorly on most or all benchmarks. But there is no "fastest" unless you carefully analyze your workload and use cases.

Comment: There's also the compatibility issue, and the fact that most serious, scalable, competitive filesystems are only available natively on Linux/Solaris/BSD and not Windows. Yep, you're stuck with NTFS.

Comment: Unfortunately, In Windows there is no other choice than `NTFS`.

Comment: For me, this is a good question since I'm not a computer scientist as @TamaraWijsman seems to be, but now I'm in the middle of a dilemma, should I give this question a downvote or upvote? if I give it up, I would express a selfish desire to thank him, on the other hand, if I give it a downvote I would contribute to rank this question into the most downvoted ones thus exposing those biased and arrogant people in here. I give it a downvote.

Answer (score 3):

You're right ext3 (and there's also ext4) is a Linux File System. Yes, it's fast but not compatible with Windows. If you want to use an ext3/4 file system you'll need a Linux OS. For Windows 8 the default NTFS file system is plenty fast as opposed to FAT32.

[Take a further read on Wikipedia about file systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems)

Answer (score 0):

Ext4 is faster (I think) than Ext3, but they are both **Linux** filesystems, and I doubt that you can get Windows 8 drivers for either ext3 or ext4. If I were you, I would stick with NTFS.